# Не корректно работают стили Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Создал новый проект Laravel в папке /var/www/ потом установил необходимые пакеты и начал верстать страницу входа в итоге когда захожу на сайт то не корректно отображается css стиль не знаю почему. Права стоят 777 владелец www-data

Вот код register.blade.php

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=asset('/css/register.css')?>" />
<body>
  <div class="signin">
    <div class="back-img">
      <div class="sign-in-text">
        <h2 class="active">Sign In</h2>
        <h2 class="nonactive">Sign Up</h2>
      </div><!--/.sign-in-text-->
      <div class="layer">
      </div><!--/.layer-->
      <p class="point">&#9650;</p>
    </div><!--/.back-img-->
    <div class="form-section">
     
      <form action="#">
        <!--Email-->
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
          <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="email" id="sample3">
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Email</label>
          <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Enter a correct Email</span>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <!--Password-->
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
          <input pattern=".{8,}" class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="sample3">
          <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Password</label>
          <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Minimum 8 characters</span>
        </div>
        <br/>
        <p class="forgot-text">Forgot Password ?</p>
        <!--CheckBox-->
        <label class="mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="checkbox-1">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-1" class="mdl-checkbox__input" checked>
        <span class="keep-text mdl-checkbox__label">Keep me Signed In</span>
      </label>
      </form>
    </div><!--/.form-section-->
    
    <button class="sign-in-btn mdl-button mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored">
      Sign In
    </button><!--/button-->
 </div><!--/.signin-->
</body>
```

сам register.css находится в папке public/css/ из браузера доступен

Вот ещё конфиг nginx:

```html
server {
    server_name new.site.com;
    root /var/www/new/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME             $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

[image: сайт]

Comment: а `css/register.css` доступен с браузера?

Comment: да доступен, проверял в другом также

Comment: так и чего у вас там в `<link rel="stylesheet"` по факту получилось?

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=asset('/css/register.css')?>" />

Comment: Там вроде как должно быть `asset('css/register.css')`, без первого слеша, судя по [докам](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-asset)

Comment: 1. Что за скриншот? Судя по нему, стили подтянулись. Или это как должно быть?

Comment: 2. href="<?=asset('/css/register.css')?>" - это "по факту получилось" (см вопрос выше)? То есть, в браузере "исходный код страницы" так выглядит?